# jQuery "DOM Content Loaded" takes 30 seconds

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I'm developing a phonegap based iOS App and having some serious startup time issues It takes 36 seconds. But in this this the only thing Safari Webinspector logs in the Timelines Section is the Event "DOM Content Loaded" which takes 34 seconds.

[image]

But what is it doing in this time ? Executing js ? really loading my DOM ?

My index.html measures 32 kb..

#### Some additional Informations:

Phonegap Version : 3.5.0

Phonegap Plugins:

```
de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer 0.8.1 "EmailComposer"
org.apache.cordova.camera 0.2.8 "Camera"
org.apache.cordova.device 0.2.8 "Device"
org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.2.6 "Notification"
org.apache.cordova.file 1.0.1 "File"
org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.6 "Geolocation"
org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.7 "Network Information"
org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 0.2.7 "Splashscreen"
org.apache.cordova.statusbar 0.1.6 "StatusBar"
```

Inculded Scripts:

```
  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type='application/javascript' src='js/libs/fastclick.js'></script>
  <script src="js/libs/hammer.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/swipeout.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/rjs.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/list.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-data.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/signature_pad.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libs/jquery.leanModal.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/bugsense.min.js" type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Comment: We can't really help you with the little information you've given us. What is happening during that time? Do you have a lot of script/style being downloaded?

Comment: Nothing downloaded it's all stored locally on the device but yes there are many scripts mainly : jquery, ember, ember-data, handlebar.js

Comment: Can you show your online demo for it?

Comment: Sadly no, because it's a phonegap app which runs on iOS

Comment: Ok I dropped most of my html and now it takes only 8 seconds so yeah it's just too much. I will try to load the rest of my html later

Comment: Try to include your `javascript files` at the end of html

Comment: they are already at the end of html